# coolify custom domain cannot be validated

Tags: dns, digital-ocean, self-hosting

On Coolify I keep getting a "Validating DNS (https://xxxx.yyyy.com) failed." message for all the bindings when I save the configuration of a simple nodejs application inside Coolify.
The error started popping up once I setup a custom domain for the coolify server.
The app loads properly in the browser when I visit those urls (with certificate applied fine)

Why do I keep getting this message and how can I get rid of it / resolve it?

The app is hosted within the coolify server (a digital ocean droplet) and nameservers are also in digital ocean)

I show how dns is setup and the error message i get in the screenshot...
[Coolify Dns Validation Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2pgZ.png)

I've setup FQDNS records and specific subdomain records in the nameserver but even if the app loads properly when I visit the urls, Coolify keeps showing me the dns validation error.